# How to access state of current scene in NavigationBar RightButton of Navigator Component

Tags: react-native

I have a page which contains a form to fill in then store to state. I also create a right button in NavigationBar named "Create". When press the right button, I like to fetch data from state of current scene so I can call the service to create the object.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible unless you maintain the state of your form in the component that handles your NavigationBar (by passing props to the form component); or you pass your state to a Store that you can call on the onPress event of the create button.

Answer (score 0):

Try set `ref` props like this `ref={c => this.sceneComponent = c}` in your `sceneComponent` and access the state in that component by `this.sceneComponent.state.formData`. This works for me but I am still looking for better solutions as I cannot extract code with ref to make my component pure.